# What is my embedded database location

Tags: database, sqlite, location, exists

Hello I am having problems with testing if my embedded datbase exists.
I created a database like follows:

```
try {

    SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("AttendanceDatabase.sqlite");

} catch (SQLiteException ex) {

}
```

And then I insert tables and data into the tables, everything works fine.  When im saving data to the database im using the the connection string as follows:

```
conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=AttendanceDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
```

Now my problem is everytime I run my program it creates the database over, and I would like to know how to test if the database exists it should not create the database over again.

I see the recomended way to do it is using the next statement:

```
if (File.Exists())
{

}
```

and I have tried using it as follows:

```
if (File.Exists("Data Source=AttendanceDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;")){
  MessageBox.Show("File Exists");
}
```

but it does not want to go into the if brackets and display "File Exists".
So I would like to know what my path should be for my embedded database, that is if thats where my problem lies?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a ton of context but if you update your check:

```
var basePath = "C:/<path to file>/";
if (File.Exists(basePath + "AttendanceDatabase.sqlite")){
    MessageBox.Show("File Exists");
}
```

You might have more luck.   If you give me more context to how you are running this I can help you with using services to lookup the file path.   You can look it up based on assembles, approot, etc.